# Как сделать блок с комментарием?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, вёрстка

Как сделать блок комментария с вот таким треугольником? 
[image]

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/GqyzdE?editors=110  вот так ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/qNpgrb?editors=110  второй вариант

Comment: Загуглите ради интереса «[css triangle online](//google.com/search?q=css+triangle+online)» — можете найти кучу онлайн генераторов, где и можно подсмотреть способы создания таких штук. В частности вот то, что вам нужно: [тыц](//triangle.designyourcode.io).

Answer (score 4):

[image: Результат]

```css
.message {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: rgb(242, 251, 255);
  border: 2px solid rgb(220, 223, 223);
}
.message:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 15px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(220, 223, 223);
  border-left: 10px solid rgb(220, 223, 223);
  z-index: -1;
}
.message:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 17px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(242, 251, 255);
  border-left: 10px solid rgb(242, 251, 255);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="message">Привет, Верунь! Ну и т.д.</div>
```